# How to migrate Powerbuilder page data to another site?

Tags: plugins

I am working on a local wordpress site with power builder plugin installed.

I have designed couple of pages and i want to replicate these pages to another wordpress site, can any one guide me how to transfer changes there?

I have tried to pickup some of records from wp-post but its not helping.

in short: i want to transfer same page design to another website.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried by switching to text mode of the page editor and then you can copy all the shortcodes of the Elementor plugin. Just paste those shortcodes in the other website.

Comment: you want me to activate default page builder? for this i will have to deactivate elementor should i go with this?

Comment: sorry i am using power builder not elementor.